# How to improve XSLT Efficiency

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a XML-File like this:

I think you could understand my XML as a table of Content.
`AElement @Name='1'` is entry **1**
The first `AElement @Name='2'` would be entry **1.1**
The `AElement @Name='3'` below this `AElement @Name='2'` would directly belong to it making them entry **1.1.1**, entry **1.1.2** and entry **1.1.3** and entry **1.1.4**
The second `AElement @Name='2'` would be entry **1.2**
and so on..

```
<ROOT>
    <AElement Name="1">
        <AElement>
          <Child1></Child1>
          <Child2>0000</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="2">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>1000</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>0100</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>U</Child1>
          <Child2>0200</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>0300</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="2">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>2000</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>N</Child1>
          <Child2>0400</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>0500</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement>   
    <AElement Name="2">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>3000</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement>
    <AElement Name="2">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>U</Child1>
          <Child2>4000</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="3">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>0600</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement> 
    <AElement Name="4">
        <AElement>
          <Child1>E</Child1>
          <Child2>0010</Child2>
        </AElement>
    </AElement>
</ROOT>
```

**Wanted result:**

For each `AElement` a table should be created
where for each `AElement` of the following step
if `AElement/Child1='E'` of that `AElement`
a table-row and table-cell should be created
this table-cell shall than be filled with the value of `AElement/Child2` of that `AElement`.

However this table should only be created IF there are any `AElement` of the following step with `AElement/Child1='E'`.

**EXAMPLE**

For each `AElement @Name='2'` a table should be created 
 where for each `AElement @Name='3'` that belongs to `AElement @Name='2'`
if `AElement/Child1='E'` of `AElement @Name='3'`
 a table-row and table-cell should be created 
 this table-cell shall than be filled with the value of `AElement/Child2` of that `AElement @Name='3'`.

So this:

```
<AElement Name="2">
    <AElement>
        <Child1>U</Child1>
        <Child2>4000</Child2>
    </AElement>
</AElement> 
<AElement Name="3">
    <AElement>
        <Child1>E</Child1>
        <Child2>0600</Child2>
    </AElement>
</AElement> 
<AElement Name="4">
    <AElement>
        <Child1>E</Child1>
        <Child2>0010</Child2>
    </AElement>
</AElement>
```

becomes this:

```
<fo:block>STEP 2  4000</fo:block>

<fo:table>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                0600
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
</fo:table>
```

**BUT** this:

```
<AElement Name="2">
    <AElement>
        <Child1>E</Child1>
        <Child2>3000</Child2>
    </AElement>
</AElement>
<AElement Name="2">
    <AElement>
        <Child1>U</Child1>
        <Child2>4000</Child2>
    </AElement>
</AElement>
```

would NOT create a table because STEP 3000 has no following `AElements @Name='3'`.

---

```
<fo:root>

    <fo:block>STEP 1  0000</fo:block>

    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    1000
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    2000
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    3000
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>



    <fo:block>STEP 2  1000</fo:block>

    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    0100
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    0300
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>



    <fo:block>STEP 2  2000</fo:block>

    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    0500
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>



    <fo:block>STEP 2  4000</fo:block>

    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    0600
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>


    <fo:block>STEP 3  0600</fo:block>

    <fo:table>
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block>
                    0010
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table>

</fo:root>
```

---

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />



    <!-- all <AElement> we consider for output, indexed by their @Name and group ID -->
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup1" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '1'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup2" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '2'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup3" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '3'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup4" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '4'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup5" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '5'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup6" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '6'][1]))
    " />
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup7" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '7'][1]))
    " />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master
        master-name="DIN-A4-Landscape"
        page-height="210mm"
        page-width="297mm"
        margin-left="1mm"
        margin-right="1mm"
        margin-top="1mm"
        margin-bottom="1mm"
            >
          <fo:region-body margin="1mm"/>
          <fo:region-before region-name="header" extent="5mm"/>
          <fo:region-after region-name="footer" extent="15mm"/>
          <fo:region-start  region-name="left"   extent="5mm"/>
          <fo:region-end    region-name="right"  extent="5mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="DIN-A4-Landscape">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">                      
            <xsl:call-template name="ink">
                <xsl:with-param name="Now" select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>

        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ink">

    <xsl:param name="Now"/>
    <xsl:param name="Next" select="$Now + 1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Ende" select="3"/>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT">
      <xsl:with-param name="nowStep" select="$Now"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="nextStep" select="$Next"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:if test="$Ende > $Now">

      <xsl:call-template name="ink">
        <xsl:with-param name="Now" select="$Now + 1"/>     
    </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:param name="nowStep"/>
        <xsl:param name="nextStep"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="AElement[@Name = $nowStep]">
            <xsl:variable name="groupId" select="generate-id()" />            
                <xsl:variable name="groupKey" select="concat($nextStep, '|', $groupId)" />
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="concat('STEP ' , $nowStep)" /></fo:block>

<xsl:variable name="group">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('InternalElementGroup',$nowStep)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:if test="count(key($group, $groupKey))>=1">

                <fo:table page-break-after="always">
                    <fo:table-body>
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$nowStep = 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('AElementGroup1', $groupKey)/AElement" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$nowStep = 2">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('AElementGroup2', $groupKey)/AElement" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$nowStep = 3">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('AElementGroup3', $groupKey)/AElement" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>


                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
</xsl:if>            
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AElement/AElement">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="Child2"/></fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

This code by @Tomalak returns the wanted result.

Comment: Yes, `count(preceding-sibling` is very slow. In C# I would use Linq to Xml instead of XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what your intended output is since you only give a single example and no further context.

I am making the following guesses:

1. All elements are pre-ordered properly in the input.
2. You have multiple `<AElement Name="1">`, each of those starts a new "section".
3. In each "section" you want multiple `<fo:block>STEP N</fo:block>`, where N is the @Name of each `<AElement>`.
4. Each of those groups should contain the elements that belong to the *next* ordinal position (i.e. STEP 1 should contain the elements that have `@Name = '2'`, and so on). This makes a total of 8 groups (N <= 8).
5. In each of those groups you want an `<fo:table>` with M rows where M is the number of `<AElement>` items that have the right @Name and contain a `<Child1>E</Child1>`.
6. All of the above needs to be XSLT 1.0

So the general order of processing would be

- for each `AElement[@Name = '1']`

  - for N = 1 .. 8

    - output `<fo:block>STEP N</fo:block>`
    - output `<fo:table> with M rows for group (N+1) </fo:table>`

I do not have a realistic 5000-element input XML to test with, but here is how I would solve this in XSLT 1.0.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
>
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <!-- all <AElement> we consider for output, indexed by their @Name and group ID -->
    <xsl:key name="AElementGroup" match="AElement[AElement/Child1 = 'E']" use="
        concat(@Name, '|', generate-id(preceding-sibling::AElement[@Name = '1'][1]))
    " />

    <!-- some random nodes, so we have something to count with -->
    <xsl:variable name="counter" select="(//node())[position() &lt; 9]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT" />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:for-each select="AElement[@Name = '1']">
            <xsl:variable name="groupId" select="generate-id()" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$counter">
                <xsl:variable name="groupKey" select="concat(position() + 1, '|', $groupId)" />
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="concat('STEP ' , position())" /></fo:block>
                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('AElementGroup', $groupKey)/AElement" />
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AElement/AElement">
        <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="Child2"/></fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Before I go into further detail about the suggested solution, please give some feedback on whether this captures your task in the first place.

Comment: Your assumptions were absoulty right.  
I just updated the question with the full XML and xslt and pdf upto STEP 3.  
So the general order of processing would be:  
•for each AElement[@Name = '1' ] (and it belongs to the current "section", as you call it)  
•for N = 1 .. 8  
•output <fo:block>STEP N</fo:block>  
•output <fo:table> with M rows for group (N+1) </fo:table>

Comment: Okay, my XSLT seems to do that. On my PC it goes through your XML in just under 10 seconds using MSXML 4.0, as I am using [msxsl.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) for quick proof-of-concept testing. YMMV. Whether the result is *correct* is for you to determine.

Comment: Under 10 seconds just for STEP 1 or for all STEPs?

Comment: All steps, all sections, the entire sample file as you gave it. You need to run it yourself to see whether it does what you expect.

Comment: Oh wait!  
  
So the general order of processing would be for STEP1:  
•for each AElement[@Name = '1']  
•output <fo:block>STEP 1</fo:block>
•output <fo:table> with M rows for group (2) </fo:table>  
  
So the general order of processing would be for STEP2:  
•for each AElement[@Name = '2']  
•output <fo:block>STEP 2</fo:block>  
•output <fo:table> with M rows for group (3) </fo:table>  
  
and so on until STEP8.  
  
Is this what you did?

Comment: Just did. And it actually works perfectly. Altough I don't understand it yet. Thank you very much!

Comment: Okay, good to hear. I can go into more detail if you want. (How long does it take on your machine?)

Comment: Okay it does not work as perfect as i tought. I will upload a new result pdf in a sec.

The Problem is that with your XSLT STEP2 gives ONE table with all Group(3). What I Need is ONE table for each AElement[@Name='2'] with all Group(3) belonging to this specific AElement[@Name='2']

Comment: The number next to the STEP 2 is the Child2 of this specific AElement[@Name='2']. That's why I used preceding-sibling in my XSLT.

Comment: To be honest with you, your comments make it rather harder to understand than easier. Make a sample XML that is not too large to include in the post and put all general cases and all corner cases in there. There aren't too many cases here anyway. Make it short, but make it complete. Remove all ambiguity. Then create a corresponding output XML for that sample input. Ignore the PDF, that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: Okay I will try that.

Comment: But if you want M tables with 1 row instead of 1 table with M rows, just create the the `<fo:table>` in the last template, where it currently creates only `<fo:table-row>`.

Comment: I just updated the question. maybe you will understand what I want better.

Comment: So you want exactly 8 steps overall in your result document and there is no such thing as "sections"? Because that's not at all what the text of my answer says, not what the code of my answer says and it was not obvious from the first version of your question. Please, for the next time. Make a complete question with unambiguous samples first, and then post it after you run it all through in your head and came to the conclusion that someone who hears about your problem for the first time in their lives will understand it properly.

Comment: Being forced to pick out the details one by one in the comments is a giant waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Yes I now see that my question was not well asked.
But your code actually nearly fullfills my needs. I still will re-edit this question for better understanding. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Especially with XSLT questions attention to detail ist key. In other languages, there is "best practices" or "common sense/experience" that lets you figure out what the OP actually needs even though they did a poor job at writing it down. In XML transformation anything is possible, usually there is no way to tell whether a result is correct or not. The more your question looks like a spec, the better. Leaving any room for guesses almost inevitably degrades the thread into a wall of comments that benefits nobody, especially not future readers.

Comment: Since you are german as well. I now re-wrote the question in german and hope that it gets clearer by that.

Comment: I appreciate the thought, but German questions are not in scope. This site is English, and English only.

Comment: My question is now answered thanks to your Code. Thank you!!

Comment: Is it? I am still struggling to understand your sample. For example, why is `<fo:block>STEP 2  4000</fo:block>` in your desired output? It has `Child 1 = 'U'`, not `'E'`. Of all the possible STEP 3 items, why does only the 0600 one show up in the output? I generally do not seem understand your requirement.

Comment: I added an example in the question hoping to make things clear.  
`0600` is the only item in the Output because it is the only STEP 3 that directly belongs to `STEP 2 4000`